# JPA dont want to fetch OneToMany Object (One Level deep)

Tags: java, spring, rest, jpa

I am using Spring Data Rest.  It works great except that I have a REST call that I need to just return the top object and not have the OneToMany object returned.

How do I do this?

For example:
So I have a Rest interface with "/States" and "StatesWithHotels".  There is a OneToMany from the State JPA object to the Hotel JPA object.  The "/States" should just return just the States and the "StatesWithHotels" should return State object with the corresponding Hotel objects.  The "StatesWithHotels" works perfect in which it returns States and Hotels.  But the "States" I just need to return just States, but it is returning both.

Answer (score 1):

So this is what I came up with.
The top level object iterated through and set the secondary object to null

for example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getStates", method = RequestMethod.GET,
headers = { "Accept=application/xml" }, produces = "application/xml")
public @ResponseBody StateList getStates() {
   List<StateList> tmpStateList = countryRepo.findByStates();       
   for(State tmpState : tmpStateList ){
        tmpState.setHotels(null);       
    }       
    StateList tmpResult = new StateList(tmpStateList );
    return tmpResult;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the fetch mode for that collection to `lazy`. This will make sure that the collection isn't retrieved until it's accessed.

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
```

If you want it not to be serialised when it's returned, you might also need to annotate it with

```
@JsonIgnore
```

Comment: I do have it as Lazy, but when the top level object is returned, REST access all the other attributes which makes the OneToMany attribute fetch the data data.  I need it not to fetch the OneToMany and just returned.

Comment: @KRico Try annotating the collection with `@JsonIgnore`.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  So I have a Rest interface with "/States" and "StatesWithHotels".  There is a OneToMany from the State JPA object to the Hotel JPA object.  The "/States" should just return just the States and the "StatesWithHotels" should return State object with the corresponding Hotel objects.  The "StatesWithHotels" works perfect in which it returns States and Hotels.  But the "States" I just need to return just States, but it is returning both.

Comment: @KRico did you try annotating the Hotels collection within States with `@JsonIgnore`?

Comment: The problem with @JsonIgnore is that when StatesWithHotels then hotels would not be in the rest output.   I needed a way to dynamically keep rest from outputing hotels when /States was called